# Add image at background, outlook problems

Tags: outlook, html-email

have problem like in title. Have email template, everything are ok, but background image doesn't work on outlook. Unfortunately most people in my country use it. Below my code:

```
    <!--@subject Email - Header @-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
{{var non_inline_styles}}

<!-- Start Image Background -->
<table class="image-background" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="22262b" background="http://met.ivycommerce.eu/glamoura_main_image.jpg">
    <tr>
        <td class="image-background" align="center" style="background: url('http://met.ivycommerce.eu/pattern.png') 0 0 repeat">
            <table class="container-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">           
                <tr>
                    <td class="separator-50" height="50">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Start Three Column -->

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="container-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="center" align="center">
                                    <a href="{{store url=""}}">
                                        <img style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;"
                                            {{if logo_width}}
                                            width="{{var logo_width}}"
                                            {{else}}
                                            width="165"
                                            {{/if}}

                                            {{if logo_height}}
                                            height="{{var logo_height}}"
                                            {{else}}
                                            height=""
                                            {{/if}}

                                            src="{{var logo_url}}"
                                            alt="{{var logo_alt}}"
                                            border="0"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Start Three Column -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="separator-30" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="60">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="separator-line" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="1">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="separator-30" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="colored-heading" align="center" height="28">
                        <div style="line-height: 28px;">Nasza Misja</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="heading" align="center" height="28">
                        <div style="line-height: 28px;">To uśmiechnięci Klienci</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="separator-10" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sub-heading" align="center" height="24">
                        <div style="line-height: 24px;">Dziękujemy, że dołączyłeś do wielkiego grona Bionaturalnych.</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td class="separator-50" height="50">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="button" align="center" valign="middle" height="38" width="140">
                                    <a href="{{store url=""}}">Wejdź Do Sklepu</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="separator-50" height="50">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Image Background -->

<!-- Begin wrapper table -->
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="background-table">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="container-td" align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="container-table">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="top-content">
                    <!-- Begin Content -->
```

I was try with some code, but not success :( when background are ok, rest align left, but have to be center. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook generally requires old school type programming and has a lot of things that are not permitted in email that are allowed in website programming. This means that the style works best when included in the header and background images cannot be used. If you want to use a background image, say behind a title for example, you would need to create the title and background as a single image to insert as you would any other image. The downside to this is that Outlook will not download images unless the user specifies to do so. Since a majority of your users use Outlook, best practices says to program for them and then test it across all other browsers. Here is a list of issues identified by Mailchimp, an email service provider, that specifically pertain to Outlook and what fixes, if available, can be performed. http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/previews-and-tests/my-campaign-looks-bad-in-outlook.

In reviewing your code provided, here are some other things that I think you might want to consider:

- Use fixed measurements instead of percentages;
- Instead of using code for spacing, use a 1px x 1px transparent or background colored image that you can adjust the height and the width of to make the space work the way you want;
- Put all styles at the top in css format, for example:

  ```
  <style type="text/css">
      body{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          font-family:"Trebuchet MS", arial, sans-serif;
      }

  </style></head>
  ```

I have been programming email newsletters for almost ten years now and the most simple, basic code works the best when the majority of your users have Outlook. Finally, I recommend that you always run your code through an html validator, such as https://validator.w3.org/ to check your code. Even the smallest error can result in unanticipated results with Outlook or other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Zydol,
To make this work, you will need to use VML to create an object and assign the background image to that. You can read more about this technique here: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_vector_markup_language_and_backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I do believe Bulletproof Backgrounds is the answer you're looking for!

https://backgrounds.cm/